# bash completion after a multiline string

Tags: bash, autocomplete, completion

I bumped into this problem regarding bash completion, can't find reference to it.

When doing

```
$ echo foo "bar" /tm<TAB>
```

I got /tm expanded to /tmp/ that is indeed correct.

But if I do

```
$ echo foo "bar
more bar" /tm<TAB>
```

No completion is done. My question is doest this behavior a feature or a bug?

My bash version is

```
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. My guess is that completion is inactive when the `PS2` prompt is active. Maybe you can suggest it as [feature request](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).  BTW, tried it out of curiosity with zsh, and zsh does completion in this situation.